# How to get data from firebase knowing the email of user ANDROID

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to get the data of my firebase database for android, knowning for example the email, but i can't do it myself.

I leave a photo for more information. [image: See the photo]

Comment: Answer below. For future questions, please share the JSON as text instead of a screenshot. You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the email address, you can get all users with that email address with a query. The code would be something like this:

```
myRef.orderByChild("correo").equalTo("email@email.es").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey()+": "+childSnapshot.child("appellidos").getValue(String.class));
        }
```